# fetch row id and load data related to id from another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

there is a action called vew boq.i want to load a grocery crud or another simple crud table when click the view boq. that crud should contain data from another new table called BOQ. and should fetch the data according to Project Id.
for an example when i click the "view boq" in first line it should load all data in boq which forign key have to equal to Project_id 1.Project id is a FK of the BOQ Table.can i do it and any one can help me.

**controller**

```
function show_boq() {
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['boq'] = $this->project_list_model->show_boq($id);
$this->load->view('boq_doc', $data);
}
```

**model**

```
function show_boq($data){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('boq');
$this->db->where('id',$data);
$this->db->join('project', 'project.id = boq.project.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
return $result;
}
```

Comment: Sure, this appears like a standard situation: you submit the chosen ID as a request argument to the server side. Either by creating individual links per row or by means of a client side logic (javascript) that evaluates the clicked row. Then on the server side you fetch the object associated with the specified ID and return the result to the client. Either as a full page reload or in background to inject it into the loaded page.

Comment: cant i do it by
 $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['projects'] = $this->project_list_model->show_projects($id);
$this->load->view('project_list_view', $data);

Comment: I have no idea about that, since you did not post your code, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

get the corresponding project id for that particular row, and use it in the select query to filter your result set.

for example,

(considering the project id value is passed as projectId or it can be another name, and there are so many other methods to do it.)

---

**select * from BOQ where project_id=projectId;**

---

This should get the results.And if you are having problem with getting the data still, then you have to check how your crud is being called in the webservice.

Comment: can you help me to get project_id of the selected row.i have a code.but there is an error. i will edit the question with my code